# Nav List Items and ::Before ::After

Tags: html, css, css-selectors, pseudo-element

Is it possible to add ::before and ::after elements to list items?

For example if I have the following:

```
<ul>
 <li>One</li>
 <li>Two</li>
 <li>Three</li>
```

Can I target the last item, let's say and add an ::after element like so, or, can I only target the actual UL element?

```
ul li:nth-child(3)::after
{
content: "";
height: 10px;
width: 10px;
background: transparent;
border: 1px solid #ccc;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes u can use, make sure to set position:absolute to use height and width for your pseudo element.

```css
ul li:nth-child(3)::after {
  display block;
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  height: 10px;
  width: 10px;
  background: transparent;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
}
```

```html
<ul>
 <li>One</li>
 <li>Two</li>
 <li>Three3</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is the working CSS - you can use `nth-child` or `last-child` for this, and `:after` does work.

http://jsbin.com/xatuve/edit?html,css,output

```
ul li:last-child:after {
  content: "";
  height: 10px;
  width: 10px;
  background: transparent;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
}
```

Comment: And yes, `display: block;` is why the `width` property isn't working.

Comment: Thanks so much Toby

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can use. Here is the demo:

```css
ul li:nth-child(3)::after
{
   content: "Test";
   height: 10px;
   width: 10px;
   background: transparent;
   border: 1px solid #ccc;
}
```

```html
<ul>
 <li>One</li>
 <li>Two</li>
 <li>Three</li>
 <li>Four</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Okay so something else must be wrong in my code.  Should it be one : or two ::

Comment: Please refer this link : http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_pseudo_elements.asp